# Is it implicit in Example 4.19 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds that the topology on the domain is the subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

At the risk of embarrassing myself: I understand the example completely *if* the answer to the question in my Title is "yes". However, if not, could someone explain to me why it is  necessary that this be so? The author states: "It is easy to see that $\beta$ is an injective smooth immersion...". I would also appreciate an explanation how, without knowing the topology on the domain, one would know $\beta$ is even continuous. Certainly we couldn't directly conclude that $(-\pi,\pi)$ is not compact.

**Disclaimer**: I realize it's my fault for not understanding this, but I really appreciate the opportunity this forum affords people to ask these kinds of questions and hopefully get answers. I just tend to be a pain about these details, agonizing over every statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(-\pi,\pi)$ has the subspace topology from $\Bbb{R}$ (which since $(-\pi,\pi)$ is an open set in the topology of $\Bbb{R}$, simply means that a set $U\subset (-\pi,\pi)$ is open in $(-\pi,\pi)$’s topology if and only if $U$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$’s topology).

Without a topology on the domain, you obviously can’t define the notion of continuity, so it is meaningless to ask if a map is continuous or not.

But seeing as this is chapter 4, I’m sure Lee has mentioned somewhere earlier in the text that when nothing else is mentioned, always assume the subspace topology for subsets of a given topological space (and I’m sure he’s careful to mention when things don’t have the subspace topology, especially in that chapter when discussing immersions, and particularly in this very example).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that one possibility is the author stated at some point  that, unless otherwise specified, we are to assume the subspace topology. It's just that it's quite a chore to go through the text and find the statement. Of course you have to have SOME topology, I just understood that in the situation described it is POSSIBLE to specify a different topology on the domain. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @user167131 right the different topologies can be a little confusing initially, but from my recollection of the text and examples, the only time you really need to be alert is when talking about the topology on the *image*, $f(M)$, of an injective immersion $f:M\to N$ (and injective immersions pop up at several places: Lie subgroups, leaves of foliations etc).

Comment: Understood, it's just that, as I said above, I like to test myself by agonizing over every little detail. Forgetting about any preceding author admonition, in theory one could put the "chaotic" topology on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and then, as you point out above,  $\beta$ wouldn't even be continuous although the domain would be compact. Anyway, as I say, thanks for the post, I'll mark your answer as correct.